# Unable to resolve service for type QR Code

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, qr-code

I'm working on a project called QR code order management with Asp net core 6.0. I'm doing the process of giving a link to the qr code created in the `QRController` class. I want to add the Name property that represents the table name in the `MenuTable` class to the link, but when I run the program, I get the error

> InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type
> `Restorant.BusinessLayer.Abstract.IMenuTableService` while attempting
> to activate `RestorantWebUI.Controllers.QRControllerController`

. Can you give me an idea for the solution?

```
public class QRControllerController : Controller
{
private readonly IMenuTableService _menuTableService;

public QRControllerController(IMenuTableService menuTableService)
{
    _menuTableService = menuTableService;
}

[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Index(int id)
{
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        QRCodeGenerator createQRCode = new QRCodeGenerator(); 
        var order =_menuTableService.TGetByID(id);
        var name=order.Name.ToString();
        string link = "https://localhost:7053/Menu/Index/" + name;
        QRCodeGenerator.QRCode squareCode = createQRCode.CreateQrCode(link, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
        using (Bitmap image = squareCode.GetGraphic(10))
        {
            image.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Png);
            ViewBag.QrCodeImage = "data:image/png;base64," + 
 Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
        }
    }
    return View();
}
}
```

Comment: Did you register `IMenuTableService`  service with the DI Container in your `Program.cs`?

Comment: Yes , builder.Services.AddScoped<IMenuTableService, MenuTableManager>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<IMenuTableDal, EfMenuTableDal>();

Comment: Can you show your Program.cs ?